# Why is the potential minimum of a molecule shifted towards greater nucleii separation for excited electron states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, molecules

I know it has to do with symmetry of the wave function, but I am having trouble piecing it all together. For a positive H ion we have a symmetric wave function $\psi_{+}$, which base functions $\phi_{a}$ and  $\phi_{b}$ overlap. This means that the bond between the nucleii will be stronger and hence closer together. For the anti-symmetric wave function $\psi_{-}$ these do not. The bond is weaker and the nucleii therefore farther apart. Now back to the first picture: How does an excited electron state (angeregter Zustand) relate to an anti-symmetric wave function? Or what is then the reason for the shift toward greater nucleii separation?